# include zeroes in count for same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with two columns, one int and another varchar column

```
SeqId   status
int     varchar(50)
```

The status column has 10 statuses, lets say status1, status2, status3, ... status10

I want to write a query to find range of SeqId where status7, status8, status9 count(*) is zero.

Table data,

```
SeqId   Status
 1   status1
 2   status2
 3   status3
 4   status4
 5   status5
 6   status6
 7   status7
 8   status8
 9   status9
 10  status10
 11  status1
 12   status2
 13   status3
 14   status4
 15   status5
 16   status9
 17   status2
 18   status7
 19   status3
 20   status5
 ......
 1000 status6
```

My 1st desired output

When I use range between 15 and 20,

Incorrect query where right now zeroes are not included,

```
 Select status, count(*) 
 from table1 
 where seqId between 15 and 20 
 group by status
```

---

```
**Status      Count**
 status1       0
 status2       1
 status3       1
 status4       0
 status5       2
 status6       0
 status7       1
 status8       0
 status9       1
 status10      0
```

Next if possible, I want to find a range where all these 3 statuses, 8, 9, and 10, are zero.

Comment: Do you have a status table? You can select from that and left join your table1 to it.

Comment: *Next if possible, I want to find a range where all these 3 statuses, 8, 9, and 10, are zero.* I have no idea what that means. Can you give an example of what the result would be in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement to turn this into a boolean problem.  So:

```
select t.*, (case when status in ('status8', 'status9', 'status10') then 0 else 1 end) as flag
from t;
```

You now want to find the longest sequence of zeros.  This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One solution is a difference of row numbers to define groups:

```
select top 1 min(id), max(id), count(*) as length
from (select t.*, 
             (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by flag order by id)) as grp
      from (select t.*, (case when status in ('status8', 'status9', 'status10') then 0 else 1 end) as flag
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where flag = 0
group by grp, flag
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Since `flag` is always zero I believe having that column in the groupings is unnecessary. I'm sure it was just left over from an earlier query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Excellent Answer!! Still trying to understand the query. Can you give me some overview?

Comment: @coder . . . Start by running the innermost subquery then the one outside it.  The difference of `row_numbers()` is a trick that defines islands.  It really helps if you run the subquery to see what the values are.  Then you'll have an "aha" moment, and get it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a status table:

```
SELECT A.STATUS, COALESCE(B.COUNT, 0) AS COUNT FROM STATUS_TABLE A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT STATUS, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY STATUS) B
ON A.STATUS = B.STATUS
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `from statustable left join table1 group by status`

Comment: @IvanStarostin If in table 1 you do not have at least one value of a certain status, it will not show up at all. The OP wants to see zeros for these cases

Comment: that's what exactly `left join` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select base.status, count(statusVal.Status) 
from table1 base 
left join ( select distinct Status from table1 
          ) statusVal 
       on statusVal.Status = base.status
where seqId between 15 and 20 
group by base.status
```

all zero

```
select SeqId from data 
except 
select SeqId from data where Status in ( ..... )
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, a generic t-sql solution will be

```
create table #t (id int, [status] varchar(12))
go
insert into #t (id, status) values
  (1   ,'status1')
 , (2   ,'status2')
 , (3   ,'status3')
 , (4   ,'status4')
 , (5   ,'status5')
 , (6   ,'status6')
 , (7   ,'status7')
 , (8   ,'status8')
 , (9   ,'status9')
 , (10  ,'status10')
 , (11  ,'status1')
 , (12   ,'status2')
 , (13   ,'status3')
 , (14   ,'status4')
 , (15   ,'status5')
 , (16   ,'status9')
 , (17   ,'status2')
 , (18   ,'status7')
 , (19   ,'status3')
 , (20   ,'status5')
 go

; WITH c (status, cnt) as
(
  select distinct [status], cnt=0 
  from #t
) 
, c2 as ( select t.[status], cnt=count(*)
 from #t t
 where t.id between 15 and 20
 group by t.[Status])
 select c.* from c2 
 right join c 
 on c.[status]=c2.[status]
 where c2.status is null
 union
select c2.* from c2;
```

For your second question, @Gordon Linoff provides an excellent solution, but I think there is a typo in his solution. The where clause should be

```
where flag = 1 -- instead of 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(int,substring(a.[status],7,2)),a.*,isnull(b.CNT,0)
from
    (select distinct [status] from #t) a
left join
    (select [status],COUNT(*)as CNT from #t
     where id between 15 and 20
     Group by [status]) b
on a.status=b.status
order by 1
```